# Did Petey actually kill himself or did someone else kill him?

Tags: plot-explanation, setup

In the movie *"[Setup](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1748197/)"*,

> When Sonny and Petey visit their friend (with the guns and drugs), Petey starts playing around with guns. Later, while Sonny and his friend were talking, they hear a shot and finds that Petey is dead and blood is splattered everywhere.

So did Petey shoot himself or did someone else shoot him? Petey is like a mob-boss's right-hand man. So could he been dumb enough to shoot himself? If someone else shot him, who was that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its heavily implied that he was indeed that big an eejit. He makes a statement prior about how he's handy with the steal, or words to that effect.
I thought it was a brilliant bit of dark humour. Unexpected and well timed. Very funny.
Getting back to your question though, yes, I believe its intended that he did accidentally shoot himself and no other party was involved. Lets be honest, we all know at least 1 gobshite like that ;-)